# Azure Functions CloudQueue AddMessageAsync QueueRequestOptions LinearRetryPolicy Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to implement linear retry policy for a cloud queue. Previously I was managing the retry logic programatically on each dequeue but I saw the RetryPolicy member on QueueRequestOptions and thought I could set up the retry policy on the first add and have the cloud queue manage retries automatically. Unfortunately the code below doesn't seem to do anything. It still retries almost immediately and it retries 5 times. I have tried setting it on the on creation and it also doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

```
await cloudQueue.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

var linearRetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), 1);

var options = new QueueRequestOptions { RetryPolicy = linearRetryPolicy };

await cloudQueue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queueItem)), null, null, options, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a colleague about this and he suggested that the retry policy probably relates to attempts to add the message to the queue and not to attempts to process the message from the queue.

I tested this by implementing IRetryPolicy and then disabling the storage emulator just before the call to AddMessageSync. Sure enough ShouldRetry is called after each failed attempt to add the message to the queue.

Hope this helps anyone who was similarly confused.

Answer (score 0):

The RetryPolicy is actually a delegate that when evaluated returns a Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.ShouldRetry delegate.It provides a lightweight mechanism to construct state-full retry instances in controlled manner. When each operation begins it will evaluate the RetryPolicy which will cause the CLR to create a state object behind the scenes containing the parameters used to configure the policy.

Example if simple linear retry policy

```
public static RetryPolicy LinearRetry(int retryCount, TimeSpan intervalBetweenRetries)
{
      return () =>
      {
           return (int currentRetryCount, Exception lastException, out TimeSpan retryInterval) =>
           { 
               // Do custom work here               
               // Set backoff
               retryInterval = intervalBetweenRetries;    
               // Decide if we should retry, return bool
               return currentRetryCount < retryCount;          

           };
      };
}
```

code inside

```
return () => {

}
```

conforms to the signature for the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.ShouldRetry delegate and will contain the specifics of your implementation.

Once you have constructed a retry policy as above you can configure your client to use it via

```
Cloud[Table/Blob/Queue].Client.RetryPolicy = LinearRetry(<retryCount, intervalBetweenRetries>).
```

It worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to be applicable to the situation I'm in as I don't have a Client, rather a ServiceClient, on the queue object. And the service client doesn't have a RetryPolicy, although there is one within the DefaultRequestOptions but rather than taking a delegate it takes an instance of IRetryPolicy. Thanks for the help though!